# printf to append blank spaces to the end of a string

Tags: java, command-line, formatting, printf

In Java is there any way to use printf to add spaces to the end of a string to ensure all strings are the same length in the command line.

I have a program which returns records but I need to display them as so...

```
 Bob          27     007895
 Christopher  32     007856
```

Essentially I want each name to take up 30 characters so the columns all align. At the moment I.m using a tab at the end of the string to create the columns but there are some names which cause all the columns to miss align (Christopher is one of them).... So im assuming there is a much better way to do this?

```
System.out.print(Bob.getName() + "\t");
System.out.print(Bob.getAge() + "\t");
Sstem.out.print(Bob.getRegnumber() + "\t");
System.out.print(Chris.getName() + "\t");
System.out.print(Chris.getAge() + "\t");
Sstem.out.print(Chris.getRegnumber() + "\t");
```

I'm outputting to the comandline not using a GUI.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [cheat sheet that summarizes the various printf symbols](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/software-dev/cheat-sheet-reference-printf-format-specifier-syntax) and how to use them.

You want to specify a particular max size for each of the fields to make sure that all of the fields line up.  If you do not specify a max size then you will get the mis-alignment again.

So something like the following format is needed:  "%-30.30s    %8d    %8d\n"

If the last field is a string and not an integer you will need something like "%-30.30s    %8d    %10.10s\n".

The "%-30.30s" will print left justified max of 30 chars.  "%10.10s" will print right justified max of 10 characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.printf( "%30s %d %d", Bob.getName(), Bob.getAge(), Bob.getRegnumber() );
```

Comment: yeah I agree, but Chris said "take up 30 characters" so I followed his directions..

Comment: Hi Marco, I just tried to run this code and I got the following error. 

java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier 'd'  Is there any chance you could tell me what Im doing wrong? I have coppied your code exactly

Comment: I supposr `getRegnumber` is a string, right? if so, you can simply replace the previous string with this: "%30s %d %s".
however @RichardChambers has posted a nice guide: you should look also at this to understand how the formatting works ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should find the max no. of chars, the name column should have.

Before printing you can get all the values, find the largest length and make the width accordingly.